# How to create set of proterties in maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

As an example I have following profiles, so I would like to know if I can group 
properties which are in "properties" tag and inject in every profile I need

```
<profile>
    <id>PROFILE NAME</id>
    <properties>
        <property1>PATH</property1>
        <property2>false</property2>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>PROFILE 2 NAME</id>
    <properties>
        <property1>PATH</property1>
        <property2>value</property2>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

What I would like to achive is:

```
<properties set name="SET">
    <properties>
        <property1>PATH</property1>
        <property2>value</property2>
    </properties>
</properties set>
<profile>
    <id>PROFILE NAME</id>
    <properties set name="SET"/>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>PROFILE 2 NAME</id>
    <properties set name="SET"/>
</profile>
```

Comment: What is the idea to group those properties?

Comment: @khmarbaise Idea is to remove duplications, as 50% of profiles in pom have the same properties, so I want to move them to one place. Rest part of profiles are not using such properties.

Comment: What kind of purpose do those properties have? Environment?

Comment: @khmarbaise most of then are Jenkins env variables `<grid.hub.url>${env.GRID_HUB_URL}</grid.hub.url>`, some is in following format `<mavenSurefirePlugin.Xmx>10g</mavenSurefirePlugin.Xmx>`